# NoMethodError, undefined method `permits_path' for #<#<Class:0xbbb3ed0>:0xbbb34b0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ROR. I'm trying to create a page for parking permit application. I encountered this problem[image]

I couldn't find the problem. Or maybe i missed something. Any help is appreciated.

This is my permit_controller.rb

```
class PermitController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_permit, only: [:show, :destroy]
  def index
    @permit = Permit.all
  end

  def new
    @permit = Permit.new
  end

  def create
    @permit = Permit.new(user_params)
    if @permit.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to your profile!"
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def show
    @permit = Permit.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_permit
    @permit = Permit.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def permit_params
    params.require(:permit).permit(:vehicle_type, :name, :studentid, :department, :carplate, :duration,:permitstart,:permitend)
  end
end
```

This is my permit/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Permit') %>
<h1>Permit Application</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@permit) do |f| %>

        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
        <%= f.label :"Vehicle Type" %>
        <%= f.text_field :vehicle_type, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :"Student ID" %>
        <%= f.text_field :studentid, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :department %>
        <%= f.text_field :department, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :"Car Plate" %>
        <%= f.text_field :carplate, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.submit "Confirm", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :permit
  get 'permit/destroy'

  get 'permit/show'

  root 'static_pages#home'

  get 'homepage/index'
  post 'permit' => 'permit#create'
  get 'permitapplication' => 'permit#new'
  get 'adminlogin' => 'admin_controller#index'
  get 'contact'=> 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  post 'users' => 'users#create'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new' #Page for a new session
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create' #Create a new session
  delete 'logout'=>'sessions#destroy' #Delete a session


  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: If you found any of the answers resolved your question, please consider accepting it as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead `resources :permit` use `resources :permits`.

Comment: He will also want to change `PermitController` to `PermitsController`

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, can I know why should i use permits instead of permit? I'm using RubyMine IDE and the autocomplete function suggest me to use permit.

In the beginning I created the controller as Permit and model name is permit too. What is the reason i need to plus s behind?

Comment: Because convention :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration

Comment: Along with convention, I'd highly suggest not using rubymine. If you're just starting out, use either a simple text editor or the text editor(s) built into your operating system. In the case of a Linux distribution, perhaps nano or vim. It'll be worth your time to not rely on an IDE.

Comment: @Tass, i am not agree with you. Rubymine is powerfull tool, it supports convention in ruby. However i not recommend it on the beginning because it makes many things for programmer, and you don't have to care about some stuff. I prefer start with something editor and nextly go on RubyMine

Comment: @BartekGładys, you're agreeing with me. I said I believe you shouldn't use rubymine if you're starting out, to instead use a text editor. Please re-read my comment.

Comment: @Tass Sorry, i didn't see your 'If you're just starting out'  :)

Answer (score 2):

The biggest issue here is you don't have permit/new in your routes.rb file.

As has already been suggested, it might be better for you to leverage rails 
with a resources call

in routes.rb

`resources :permits`

and remove lines

`get 'permit/destroy'`
`get 'permit/show'`

etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As the permit/new cannot be done by this line?   get 'permitapplication' => 'permit#new'

Can I know why need to use permits? instead of permit? I'm currently using RubyMine IDE and the autocomplete function suggest me to use permit instead of permits

Comment: @GaryVlc, you **should** use `permits` because you **should** be using `PermitsController`. (This is also why someone suggested below this post that you should change your controller's name.) I recommend reading about Rails routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: To further complement this answer, you're calling `<%= form_for(@permit) do |f| %>` in your form, which assumes `Rails` is going to interpret the intended route for you. (In this case, `permits#new`.) You can either update your form to use the custom route, or update your controller and `routes.rb` to do things `The Rails Way.`

Comment: I changed to permits and it worked. Is ruby very strict on the plural singular stuff?

Comment: Ruby on Rails has a "convention over configuration" philosophy that basically saves you a lot of reading of configuration files and XML hell.

Comment: In order to take full advantage of the RESTful routes/routing, you really ought to do things like simply adding `resources: permits` to `routes.rb`. (and naming your resources in accordance with Rails best practices). Together with your controller's methods, `Rails` will know which routes to use, making your life as a developer easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'll attempt to consolidate our various answers and comments.

To solve your current problem, in `config/routes.rb`, change `resources :permit` to `resources :permits`. This exposes all seven RESTful routes for use in your application. (This also makes obsolete the custom `permit` routes, unless you're explicitly calling them from within their respective forms.) Information about RESTful routes/resources here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Why is this valuable?

It's how your application knows to use controller actions in combination with views (and therefore forms). Say you have an edit action in your permits controller and `app/views/permits/edit.html.erb` has a form. Within this page's edit form, you need only have `form_for @permit` and Rails does all the rest. It knows you're using this particular route. I recommend you read about routing within `Rails.`

Please keep in mind `Ruby on Rails` has been carefully crafted to make things easy for you, the developer.